# Discord.py: How would you restrict a certain command to a role or people with specific permissions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Could someone show how you'd restrict, for example, the following command to lets say a role named 'Moderator' or only to people that have kick permissions? I don't quite understand how that'd work.

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member)
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been kicked.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restrict commands to certain roles named "Moderator" or "Admin" use **has_any_role**

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Moderator", "Admin")
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} has been kicked.')
```

To restrict commands to certain permissions of roles for example if a role has administrator you use **has_permissions**

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} has been kicked.')
```