# Discord.py how to make a command work for certain roles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this code which if someone has a role "Server Developer" it is suppose to run the command which is to give someone the role "Jail" for the determent amount n the command but it doesn't work and gives no errors.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re
import time
from time import sleep
import asyncio

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

@commands.has_role("Server Developer")
@bot.command()
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):
    user_id = message.mentions[0].id
    user = message.mentions[0]
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    await user_mentioned.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(
        f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await user_mentioned.remove_roles(role)

bot.run(TOKNE_GOES_HERE)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65671959/discord-py-how-would-you-restrict-a-certain-command-to-a-role-or-people-with-sp) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `@bot.command()` on top of your command. Add it between `@commands.has_role("Server Developer")` and `async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):`

Do it like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re
import time
from time import sleep
import asyncio

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

@commands.has_role("Server Developer")
@bot.command()
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):
    user_id = ctx.message.mentions[0].id
    user = ctx.message.mentions[0]
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    await user_mentioned.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(
        f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await user_mentioned.remove_roles(role)

bot.run(TOKNE_GOES_HERE)
```

Comment: Can you try moving `@bot.command()` to on top of `@commands.has_role("Server Developer")`?

Comment: Does it give any errors? Maybe try adding a print statement to the command to see if the command gets called or not

Comment: no erors and iv tried that it doesn't print

Comment: Are you calling the command correctly? And I'm not seeing any definition of `bot` in the code. Did you define `bot`?

Comment: yes i do have that but its not in the question its like this 

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

Comment: Please try calling the command like this: `$court @SomeUser 10` and replace @SomeUser with a user in your server.

Comment: thats how iv been doing it al along

Comment: After editing the post I saw that you defined `bot` before importing `commands`. If thats the case in the actual code, please put `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")` under the `import` statements

Comment: its not in the code the imports are first

Comment: Try removing `@commands.has_role("Server Developer")` to see if the command itself works or not. If it doesn't respond, the problem is something else. If it doesn't work, please check if you are saving the files and restarting the bot every time you make a change.

Comment: it sais messege is not defined and i did try to add it like this `message = message.content` but then it said message has no atrebute content

Comment: Do `ctx.message` instead of `message`.

Comment: it sais "module 'ctx' has no attribute 'message" iv done it like this `message = ctx.message`

Comment: No, I updated my answer. Use the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Using any check decorators like `has_role` or `is_owner`, doesn't make the function a command, so you would still have to add `@commands.command()` or `@bot.command()`:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Server Developer")
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):
    user_id = message.mentions[0].id
    user = message.mentions[0]
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    await user_mentioned.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(
        f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await user_mentioned.remove_roles(role)

bot.run(TOKNE_GOES_HERE)
```

Comment: i have done that from the other comment but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you maybe called your bot variable something different than `bot`?

Comment: il try that now

Answer (score -2):

you could try adding a check inside the command, something like this:

```
if not discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Server Developer") in ctx.user.roles:
    return
else:
    # do something
```

Comment: This is not a good way of adding role checks. The decorators do the job.

Comment: from what I can see around here the decorator didn't work for him, so here's my non efficient solution

Comment: The decorator does work. You can see my answer on the question.